# How to use attributes on controller action parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating an ASP.net Core Web API, and trying to enforce a `MaxLength` constraint on a parameter of one of my actions like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody, MaxLength(200)]IEnumerable<ExampleModel> values)
{
    ...
}
```

However, the *MaxLength* attribute is not applied to the input value, so no validation errors are thrown when the *MaxLength* is exceeded.

Is there any way to enforce this constraint without having to create a model just to wrap the *IEnumerable* of my *ExampleModel*?

Comment: `MaxLength` applies only to `string` and `Array` types.

Comment: Recheck your tags as `IActionResult` relates to `asp.net-core`

Comment: @Amy While the documentation is misleading, I think you'll find through testing that it works for all *IEnumerables*.

Comment: @user40857 you would probably need to create a custom action filter to enforce that max length on the values.

Comment: @user40857 Just tested it with `var mla = new MaxLengthAttribute(2);  var foo = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4,5};  var result = mla.IsValid(foo)`  which throws an exception.  It only works if the value under test can be cast to an `Array`.

Comment: @Amy I see. Are you using ASP.net core 2? Because in my project it works fine for all of my IEnumerables nested inside of objects.

Comment: @user40857 `IEnumerable<T>` are not concrete types, so an object of that type does actually have a *real* concrete type that is not `IEnumerable<T>`. If that real type is an array, it will work. If it is not, you will get an `InvalidCastException` exception.

Comment: @Amy I should probably mention that I've tried switching the type from IEnumerable to Array, and this still did not solve the problem

Comment: @poke Please see above comment

Comment: *“It did not solve the problem”* is not a clear description of what’s happening. Please show what you are trying and what the actual problem is.

Comment: @poke Please see the description in my initial question for the description of what is happening.